# R Programming Formatting data

Tags: r, formatting

I want to store a array of numbers in a 3-digit format as 001 ,002 etc. But when i try to use the auto fill it gets stored as 1,2,3 only.

How do i store a array of numbers as 001,002 etc rather than 1,2,3 in R programming ? I did search but not able to find a suitable answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use sprintf like this:

```
# create the n variable which is the number of numbers stored in the array
n <- 10
vector <- sprintf("%03d", 1:n)
```

this returns:

```
[1] “001” “002” “003” “004” “005” “006” “007” “008” “009” “010”
```

Comment: [Here](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Strings/Creating_strings_from_variables/) is a good site to learn more about the sprintf command